# Mismatched value (page crawl) [price]

Tags: shopify, currency, catalog, google-merchant-center

I've seen all my catalog of products on Google Merchant Center being suddenly disapproved while it has been running fine for years.

The error displayed is "Mismatched value (page crawl) [price]".

According to Google, the value in feed is 54.00 EUR when the value on website is 57.00 USD.

My website, based on Shopify, is set up in Euros, with an "auto switcher" for currencies.
So it would suggest the bot is from the US and getting prices in USD.
I can't remove the switcher since it represents a large majority of our revenues.

1. How to force Google to visit the website from a Euro-country?
2. Why does it happen suddenly after 3 years?
3. Is there a solution to this error?

Comment: I suggest you to contact Google support. And if you're on Shopify Plus, Shopify support.